# to redirect a page according to the selected option value

Tags: php

I want to redirect a page according to selected option value if i select one from option tag than it will be redirect google.com page else i selected another option it will be redirect on gmail.com page.I write these code but it will redirect same value if i select another option any solution for these.

```
<?php
$package = isset($_GET['package_select']);
if ($package == 'one') 
{
    header("Location: http://google.com");
}
else if ($package == 'two') 
{
    header("Location: http://youtube.com");
} 

?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="#" method="get" id="packageForm" >
 <select name="package_select">
        <option value="">Select package</option>
        <option value="one">One listing</option>
        <option value="two">Two listings</option>
    </select>
<input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `isset($_GET['package_select'])` will always be considered as being set.

Comment: @Fred-ii- unless the form hasn't been submitted yet, right?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Kind/sort of ;-) funny what an `if` will do huh?

Answer (score 2):

`isset` will return `true` or `false` depending on whether or not the given variable is set. So when you do this:

```
$package = isset($_GET['package_select']);
```

`$package` will be either `true` or `false`.

So when you compare it with `if ($package == 'one')` or `else if ($package == 'two')`, those equalities will never be achieved correctly. If either `one` or `two` is selected, then `$package == 'one'` will evaluate to true, because `true` is equal to both `'one'` and `'two'` when compared using `==`, and you'll always get the first redirect.

---

Instead, you can use a built-in filter function to assign the value of `$_GET['package_select']` to `$package`, or a `null` value if `$_GET['package_select']` is not set. (This would only be the case if the form had not been submitted. If the empty "Select package" option was selected, then `isset($_GET['package_select'])` would still return `true`.)

```
$package = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'package_select');
```

Then your `if`/`elseif` will work properly, because `$package` can contain either `one` or `two` instead of a bool.

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
if(isset($_GET['package_select'])){
    if ($_GET['package_select'] == 'one') 
    {
        header("Location: http://google.com");
        exit;
    }
    else if ($_GET['package_select'] == 'two') 
    {
        header("Location: http://youtube.com");
        exit;
    }
}
```

Or, better yet...

```
if(isset($_GET['package_select'])){
    switch($_GET['package_select']){
        case('one'):{ header("Location: http://google.com"); exit; }
        case('two'):{ header("Location: http://youtube.com"); exit; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure but can you explain why their syntax failed in the first place? There is a reason you know.

Comment: it's also best to add `exit;` after each header.

Comment: That's a good point, @Fred-ii-.  I'll update the answer to reflect the best practice.